# Shortcode for Listing Users from Meta Value?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, user-roles, user-meta

Trying to display a list of users that match certain criteria using a shortcode with parameters. Here is what I have so far, but for some reason it does not display anything. I am pretty new at this stuff, so if anybody has examples of changes that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Shortcode for Listing Users from Meta Data
 * Usage: [list_users key="green-eyes" value="Yes" userrole="x-genes,y-genes"]
 */
function users_from_meta($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'key'   => '',
        'value' => '',
        'userrole'  => '',
    ), $atts );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
        'meta_key' => $atts['key'],
        'meta_value' => $atts['value'],
        'role__in'    => wp_parse_list( $atts['userrole'] ),
    ) );
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    if (!empty($users)) {
        $results = '<ul>';
        foreach ($users as $user){
            $results = '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
        }
        $results =  '</ul>';
    } else {
        $results =  'No users found';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $results;
}
add_shortcode( 'list_users', 'users_from_meta' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's a small coding mistake..**

It's not displaying anything because when there are results, the end output is always a `</ul>` because you're always overwriting the `$results` and not appending output to the variable:

```php
$results = '<ul>';
foreach ($users as $user){
    $results = '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
}
$results = '</ul>';
```

So the proper code is:

```php
$results = '<ul>';
foreach ($users as $user){
    $results .= '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
}
$results .= '</ul>';
```

And there's no need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` because in your code, there's no call to any functions which modifies the global `$post` object/data.